# How to detach if an application has closed

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is there a way to check if an application has just been closed? Not specifically my application. I want to know if the notes application has closed for example. Or if safari has exited.

Is this possible? and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register for the `NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification`:

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self
                        selector:@selector(appTerminatedNotification:)
                            name:NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification
                          object:nil];
```

The notification is posted when an application terminates, and the `userInfo`
of the notification contains information about the terminated app:

```
-(void)appTerminatedNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"%@ terminated", [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSApplicationName"]);
}
```

Comment: sounds promising. I'll give it a try and close it if it works.